# Django: Compound urls

Tags: python, django, url

I am trying to create a simple office administration site for my company.  I have a main template which lists the employees.  Each employee is a link in the template html.

```
<a href="{% url 'personnel:employee_detail' employee_id=employee.id %}">{{ employee }}</a>
```

Which links to view:

```
def employee_detail(request, employee_id, **kwargs):

    payslips = Payslip.objects.filter(employee_id=employee_id)
    if not kwargs:
        active_payslip = Payslip.objects.filter(
            employee_id=employee_id,
            date=payslips.latest('date').date
        )
    else:
        active_payslip = Payslip.objects.filter(
            employee_id=employee_id,
            date='%s-%s-%s' % (year, month, day)
        )

    return render(request, 'employee_detail.html', {'active_payslip': active_payslip, {'payslips': payslips})
```

and the url (going from the main page to employee_detail page:

```
url(r'^employee-main/(?P<employee_id>\d+)/$', employee_detail, name='employee_detail')
```

Now that I am on that employee, I have a ul and li elements with specific dates where that employee was paid.  The active pay date will be the latest date.  I would like to click on one of the links to open the same page again, but with the chosen link active:

```
<ul>
    {% for payslip in payslips %}
    {% if payslip.date = active_payslip.date %}
    <li><b>{{ payslip.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}</b></li>
    {% else %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'personnel:employee_detail_specific' employee_id=payslip.employee_id year=payslip.date|date:'Y' month=payslip.date|date:'m' day=payslip.date|date:'d' %}">{{ payslip.date|date:"Y-m-d" }}</a></li>
```

Which should pass to the following url:

```
url(r'^employee-main/(?P<employee_id>\d+)/(?P<year>\w+)/(?P<month>\w+)/(?P<day>\w+)/$', employee_detail, name='employee_detail_specific')
```

It should pass to a different url than before, but the same view and html template.  The url that I receive when clicking on a payslip link is the following:

```
employee-main/14/%7B%%20url%20'personnel:employee_detail_specific'%20employee_id=payslip.employee_id%20year=payslip.date%7Cdate:'Y'%20month=payslip.date%7Cdate:'m'%20day=payslip.date%7Cdate:'d'%20%7D
```

And a 404 Page not found error.  I am not sure if it is a date error in the url or because I am attempting a compound url (2 variables)?

Comment: Hi, I assume that you are referring to the first template url?  Yes, it is just a link to the specific employee, but I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, I restarted the server, but still does not work.  I edited my question again.  The employee_id from payslip is exactly the same as employee.id.

Comment: You're 100% certain that the template is exactly the same as in your question? You copied and pasted the exact code? I ask because the code in your question looks ok to me, I can't see why it would result in the url that you are seeing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about two variables. You have four variables in that URL.